# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' : while comparing base domain name and child domain name on crawling website

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm trying to find out the internal link ratio of a particular website by calculating the total number of internal links to the total links in the webpage.If the ratio is >= 0.5 ,it will return -1 else it will return 1.

```
def get_domain_name(url):
   splitted = urlparse(url).hostname.split('.')
   return  splitted[-2] + '.' + splitted[-1]


def internal_link(url):
   icount = 0
   count = 0

   base_domain_name = get_domain_name(url)
   page = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
   href_links = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
   for link in href_links:
       count = count + 1
       child_domain_name = get_domain_name(link)
       if child_domain_name == base_domain_name:
           icount = icount + 1   

   if count != 0 :
       ilink_ratio = icount/count
        #elink_ratio = 1 - ilink_ratio
   else: 
       ilink_ratio = 0


   if ilink_ratio >= 0.5:
       return -1
   else:
       return 1


ans = internal_link('https://www.google.com')
print(ans)
```

my expected output will be either 1 or -1 but i am getting

```
ans = internal_link('https://www.google.com')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-76-aa8cd733497f>", line 1, in <module>
ans = internal_link('https://www.google.com')

File "<ipython-input-75-36aae0789101>", line 17, in internal_link
child_domain_name = get_domain_name(link)

File "<ipython-input-75-36aae0789101>", line 2, in get_domain_name
splitted = urlparse(url).hostname.split('.')

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 367, in urlparse
url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 123, in _coerce_args
return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 107, in _decode_args
return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 107, in <genexpr>
return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)

File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1181, in decode
indent_space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_domain_name` function doesn't handle all the corner cases.

```
def get_domain_name(url):
   if url:
       print(url)
       hostname = urlparse(url).hostname
       if hostname is not None and '.' in hostname:
           splitted = hostname.split('.')
           return  splitted[-2] + '.' + splitted[-1]
```

This might just work. But you have look for other corner cases. I have only tried with the url you have mentioned in the post.